# Check if a div element can receive paste event i.e if it is focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am capturing a paste event in a div element.

```
<div onPaste={(e)=>console.log(e.clipboardData.getData("Text"))}}>
</div>
```

This, however only works if the element has been clicked into (and the user hasn't clicked outside of it)

How do I indicate to the user that the element is able to receive a paste (i.e is focused, I suppose)

`document.activeElement` remains focused on body I suppose because the div is not an input

Comment: If the target is not an input element on blur, then just restyle it as active.

Comment: div doesn't seem to receive focus/blur events

Comment: Ah, I thought you were concerned about having the div become the focus from an input element. You can use contenteditable in order to gain focus blur events, or use an internal, hidden, full bleed input element inside of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You should use react hook useState for that:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {

  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false)

  const onFocus = () => {
    setFocused(true)
  }

  const onBlur = () => {
    setFocused(false)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div onFocus={onFocus} onBlur={onBlur}>{focused ? 'focused' : 'not focused'}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

And now if the `focused` variable is true, the element is focused and if it's false the element is blurred.

Comment: onfocus doesn't work. i don't think focus/blur events work for non input elements